# Hardware Identification on UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

ASHWID is comprising of the below parameters

Byte Stream representation       Component

1,0          Processor

2,0          Memory

3,0          Disk Device

4,0          Network Adapter

5,0          Audio Adapter

6,0          Docking Station

7,0          Mobile Broadband

8,0          Bluetooth

9,0          System BIOS

Question A: Which All above components will not change when we upgrade OS version?

Question B: I have a requirement to have a unique ID /per device for hardware identification(for Desktop and mobile), Can I rely on ASHWID?

Question C: Apart from ASHWID, Can I rely on any other ID for hardware identification for UWP?

Question D: If the same ID cannot be used in both Mobile and Desktop, is there any solution which can work on Mobile and  a different solution which can work on Desktop ?

Comment: Please check the reply in this  link [Hardware Identification on UWP](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/fc35298d-f02e-4da5-b494-d08d834d15a6/uwphardware-identification-on-uwp?forum=wpdevelop) .